# JavaScript: How to set a date so that it looks the same all over the world?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, save, dst

One of our programmers decided to use a DATE field in the MySQL db in order to achieve this.
Sending and saving a JS date object did work well until the daylight saving changes intervened (with nasty effects :) ).
Of course, saving the date in a DATETIME field solves it, but everybody sees the time/dates in their own timezone.
We need everybody (all over the timezones) to see the same date!

---

I clarify this, to get the proper answers:

I want to keep using the DATE field storage type in MySQL (vs DATETIME - ok, maybe too much of an optimization, but it's already there and I want a long term solution for when I receive such structure/code from other developers)

Sending local time (local JS in browser) 23-05-2016, will reach the server as 22-05-2016 0X:X0:00Z (UTC) and be store as such. Because it's a DATE field, the stored value will become 22-05-2016 only. And you lost a day! :)

Our solution from bellow not only fixes the DATE field trimming, but also adds the fact that people now can see the same correct date (23-05-2016) no matter of the timezone they are in!

I like the outcome and would love to see some better solutions to achieve the same and improve the system.

Actually, we have noticed the problem only when the daylight saving time changed, so my solution (as answer bellow) is a good solution for that as well. And it only consumes resources client-side.

*I have posted my own solution to this question as an answer bellow.*

It would be really cool to see a much better solution from you!

Answer (score 1):

### With Javascript

Save your dates in ISO format (including timezone information) and use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) to convert the datetime to another timezone.

If `moment.js` is not already a dependency, and you want to avoid extra libraries, keep reading.

### With MySQL

Instead of solving this problem when you *write* the data (losing timezone information in the process), solve it when you *read* the database.

In your `SELECT` query, normalize all `DATETIME` values to your preferred timezone using the [`convert_tz`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) built-in function.

Comment: convert_tz is news for me thanks!
However, SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+00:00','+10:00');
cannot get a dynamic parameter without complicating the system too much (e.g. having to pass data). Please look at my updated question. I have added some clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

MomentJs is your best bet. Find the timezone you want and pass the ISO string to it and you should be good to go.
http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

Comment: I see what you mean
moment.tz("May 12th 2014 8PM", "MMM Do YYYY hA", "America/Toronto");
It works, but takes up a little more resources (parameters and the lib itself). We don't have enough interactions with these datatypes to justify including it. I love moment.js, by the way.

Comment: Please look at my updated question. I have added some clarifications

Answer (score 0):

There are more solutions to this, but the fastest and easiest that I could come up with is described bellow:

Let's intervene as early as possible in the information stream.
Just change the data before transmitting it through AJAX.

The function we used is this:

```
    function addTimezoneDiffAnd12HoursToDate(date) { 
            var timezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
            date.setHours(12-Math.floor(timezoneOffset/60)); 
            date.setMinutes(-timezoneOffset % 60); 
            return date;
    }
```

What it does is that it converts a Date to be always at noon (12:00) **UTC**!

You can use it like this:

```
    $scope.contract.contractDate = addTimezoneDiffAnd12HoursToDate($scope.contract.contractDate);
```

and send it as such to be stored in the DATE field.

Let me know if you have a simpler solution. I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

A `DATE` is just a year, month, and day.  It doesn't have a time, or a time zone.  Think about your birthday or your wedding date, or today's date.

The JS `Date` object is not this at all. It's a timestamp.  It's the number of milliseconds elapsed since Midnight January 1st 1970 UTC.

You should leave your date as a date-only wherever possible.  Use the ISO-8601 date-only format, which is `YYYY-MM-DD`.  If you have to assign it a time and time zone, then be very careful when you do.

If you just assign midnight local time, then you're risking losing a day (as you showed), and you're not considering that there are local days in some time zones where midnight does not exist! (Such as the spring-forward day in Brazil).   Noon is a safer bet than Midnight, but still you should use this sparingly.  The better approach is to keep dates as dates, not as date-times.

Also, I'd answer with code if I could, but you didn't provide any code in your question showing what was broken.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, 
This is kind of what I did, Thanks for the confirmation. 
Please see the code of addTimezoneDiffAnd12HoursToDate in my answer.
What I am doing in my solution is to send the date always at noon (12:00) UTC!